# Async and await in Vuejs

Tags: rest, promise, vue.js, async-await, axios

I have trouble retrieving data from a REST-API using VueJS, axios, Async/Await with Promise(??). 
I need to call two different REST-APIs. One is giving me a list and I can iterate through it, which is fine.

```
<template>
  <div>
  <div v-if="posts && posts.length">
    <div v-for="post of posts">
       {{post.name}}        
       <img :src="getUserPicturePath(post.name)" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The other, as you can see, in between the v-for, is calling a method which is using axios.

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data: () => {
    posts: []
  }
  created() {
  // a method to fill up the post-array
 },
   methods: {
    async getUserPicturePath(name){
      const response = await axios.get('linkToApi'+name)
      console.dir(response.data.profilePicture.path)
      return response.data.profilePicture.path
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The `console.dir(response.data.profilePicture.path)`- Part is giving the correct Path to the profilePicture, but the `<img :src="getUserPicturePath(post.name)" />` above in the `<template>`, writes `[Object Promise]`.

Any suggestion how I can get the path?

Comment: I am currently having the exact same issue as you with very similar code, my image returns `src="[object Promise]"`, how did you get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Vue can't resolve promises in properties so you have to do something like this.

**Template**

```
<div v-for="post of posts">
  ...
  <img :src="post.profilePicture" />
  ...
```

**JavaScript**

```
export default {
  created() {
    this.posts = ...
    await Promise.all(this.posts.map(async post => {
      post.profilePicture = await this.getUserPicturePath(post.name);
    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can maybe go with

```
<template> 
   ...
   <img :src="img_path" v-if="img_path">
   ...
</template>
<script>
   ...
   data() {
       ...
       img_path: "",
       img: "userImg.png"
   }

   // or however you wish to pass user image and trigger loading
   create() {
      this.getUserPicturePath(this.img)
   },

   methods: {
      getUserPicturePath(name){                 
            axios.get('getImage/'+name)
                .then(response => {
                    this.img_path = response.data.path
                    console.dir(response.data.path)
                })
                .catch(error =>{
                    // ... error
                })                
        },        
   }
```

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't directly answer the question at all, it uses promises instead of async/await as a workaround.

Comment: I downvoted because there are multiple profile pictures that get assigned to a single `data` property. Or this answer is meant as a stand-alone component which is not clear (and doesn't use `props`).